# What is simpler way to achieve an if then else if else stack in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, conditional-statements

Is there a way to simplify this or a more terse form i can use? The logic contained is all correct. It just seems like a lot of `return`s and `else if`s.

```
mode = (function(mode, current, proposed, origins, destinations) {
            if (mode === 'none') {
                return 'project';
            } else if (proposed.count === 0) {
                return 'unseated';
            } else if (current.count > proposed.count && proposed.count > 0) {
                return 'reducing';
            } else if (proposed.count === destinations.count && destinations.count > 1 && current.count === 0) {
                return 'newplus';
            } else if (proposed.count === destinations.count && current.count === 0) {
                return 'new';
            } else if (proposed.count > destinations.count) {
                return 'increasing';
            } else if (proposed.count === destinations.count && destinations.count > origins.count) {
                return 'moveplus';
            } else {
                return 'move';
            }
        }(moves.register[staff].move, {count: mode.currentDesks}, {count: mode.proposedDesks}, {count: mode.origins}, {count: mode.destinations})));
```

I previously used a nested ternary which is marginally shorted but i would argue more prone to error and difficult to read (*the results are marginally different due to code evolution not errors in replication*):

```
mode = 
(moves.register[staff].move === 'none') ? 'project' :
    (mode.proposedDesks === 0) ? 'unseated' :
        (mode.currentDesks > mode.proposedDesks && mode.proposedDesks > 0) ? 'reducing' :
            (mode.proposedDesks === mode.destinations && mode.destinations > 1 && mode.currentDesks === 0) ? 'newplus' :
                (mode.proposedDesks === mode.destinations && mode.currentDesks === 0) ? 'new' :
                    (mode.proposedDesks > mode.destinations) ? 'additional' :
                        (mode.proposedDesks === mode.destinations && mode.destinations === mode.origins) ? 'move' :
                            (mode.proposedDesks === mode.destinations && mode.destinations > mode.origins) ? 'moveplus' :
                                'other';
```

So while I like the `if…then…elseif` stack for legibility, it feels like it is more verbose than it could be. I don't think i'm looking for a `switch…case` version doesn't quite cut it due to the number of comparison variables, and it feels wrong to nest `if` statements within a `switch…case` or ternary operators within an `if…then…else`.

I think instinctively i'd like a form of matrix where the return values are in a grid and somehow a matrix calculation of the the various bitwise conditions returned the correct result. I suspect though that would be a win of compact code over legibility.

Any suggestions?

*NB. The variable names including the addition of a count property to each instead of naming the variable as such or not indicating that it is a count are chosen for legibility.*

Answer (score 0):

you can use a var to store your choice and return it at the end

```
    mode = (function(mode, current, proposed, origins, destinations) {
                var varName='move';
                if (mode === 'none') {
                    varName='project';
                } else if (proposed.count === 0) {
                    varName='unseated';
                } else if (current.count > proposed.count && proposed.count > 0) {
                    varName= 'reducing';
                } else if (proposed.count === destinations.count && destinations.count > 1 && current.count === 0) {
                    varName= 'newplus';
                } else if (proposed.count === destinations.count && current.count === 0) {
                    varName='new';
                } else if (proposed.count > destinations.count) {
                    varName= 'increasing';
                } else if (proposed.count === destinations.count && destinations.count > origins.count) {
                    varName= 'moveplus';
                }             
}(moves.register[staff].move, {count: mode.currentDesks}, {count: mode.proposedDesks}, {count: mode.origins}, {count: mode.destinations})));
```